# Can I use Spring @Value to retrieve its value from a Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When our application starts up, it reads data from a number of sources in to a god-like object that contains all the config items for the application.

Whenever the application needs to access any of this config information, it makes a call to this object ( either via a static method call, or via a bean that we have created that just wraps the static object )

Is it possible for me to wire this object up to the @Value/PropertySource annotations within Spring? Is it advisable?

Our environment object is populated before the spring application context is started.

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config) describes the supported locations for setting @Values.  So it depends what _reads data from a number of sources_ means.

Comment: May I ask, if you already have static accessors and a `@Bean` wrapper, why do you consider using `@Value`? Just for a cleaner look? I'm curious.

Comment: @JettoMartínez : yeah - it's just for a cleaner look and to make the code a little more easily understood by new developers coming from a Spring background.